# Finding the minimum of a function of two variables

Tags: optimization, contest-math, lagrange-multiplier

> Find the smallest value of $\displaystyle \sqrt{49+a^2-7{\sqrt{2}}\ a}+\sqrt{a^2+b^2-{\sqrt{2}}\ ab}+\sqrt{50+b^2-10b}\quad \quad$ for $a,b$ real and positive.

---

What I've done so far:
Let $F(a,b)=\displaystyle \sqrt{49+a^2-7{\sqrt{2}}\ a}+\sqrt{a^2+b^2-{\sqrt{2}}\ ab}+\sqrt{50+b^2-10b}$

Then
$$\begin{align}
\displaystyle F_a=\frac{2a-7{\sqrt{2}}\ a}{2\sqrt{49+a^2-7{\sqrt{2}}\ a}}+\frac{2a-\sqrt{2}\ b}{2\sqrt{a^2+b^2-{\sqrt{2}}\ ab}}=0\\
\displaystyle F_b=\frac{2b-{\sqrt{2}}\ a}{2\sqrt{a^2+b^2-{\sqrt{2}}\ ab}}+\frac{2b-10}{2\sqrt{50+b^2-10b}}=0
\end{align}$$ 
I then tried to simplify the two equations as follows:
$$\begin{align}
\left({2a-7{\sqrt{2}}\ a}\right)\left(\sqrt{a^2+b^2-{\sqrt{2}}\ ab}\right)+\left({2a-\sqrt{2}\ b}\right)\left(\sqrt{49+a^2-7{\sqrt{2}}\ a}\right)=0\\
\left({2b-{\sqrt{2}}\ a}\right)\left(\sqrt{50+b^2-10b}\right)+\left(2b-10\right)\left(\sqrt{a^2+b^2-{\sqrt{2}}\ ab}\right)=0\\
\end{align}$$
But then I'm stuck.

*Do I need to include a constraint?(i.e $a$ and $b$ are positive and real); if so what will the constraint equation be?*

*Is there an altogether different way to do this other than using Lagrange??*

Comment: wolframalpha gives a minimum of $13$ at $\displaystyle (a,b)=\left(\frac{35 \sqrt 2}{17},\frac{35}{12}\right)$

Comment: 1. You don't need a constraint; you have two equations and two variables, which is all you need. ("Real and positive" just gives an inequality, not an equality, on the set of solutions. 2. this problem seems algebraically too complicated; either there is a trick or it arose in real life rather than a textbook. But I can't see the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider vectors $X, A, B, Y$ where $|X| = 7$, $|A| = a$, $|B| = b$, $|Y| = \sqrt{50}$ and $\angle XOA = 45^\circ$, $\angle AOB = 45^\circ$, $\angle BOY = 45^\circ $.

How does your expression relate to these vectors? Think of distances. Apply Cosine rule.

Hence, the minimum is $ \sqrt{7^2 + (\sqrt{50})^2 - 2 \times 7 \times \sqrt{50} \times \cos 135^\circ} = \sqrt{49 + 50 + 70} = 13 $.

Comment: How do you move from the sum of $3$ distances to a single distance calculation?

Comment: @K.Rmth Work through the hint. The shortest distance between 2 points is the straight line distance.

Answer (score 1):

Comment to the earlier hint: Consider a triangle XOY where $|OX|=7$ and $|OY|=\sqrt{50}$. Then that expression is equal to $|XY|$. The minimum for $|XY|$ is achieved when $∠XOY=135^∘$.
Then the law of cosine give you the  minimum for $|XY|$ namely the minimum value for the original expression.

Comment: If we consider a triangle $XOY$, doesn't the minimum for $|XY|$ occur at $\angle XOY=0^o$ ?

Comment: Following the previous hint we have the triangle XOY and in the inside the triangles XOA, AOB, BOY where $∠XOA=∠AOB=∠BOY=45^∘$. So the minimum of $∠XOY$ is $∠XOA + ∠AOB + ∠BOY = 135^∘$.
If you draw the triangles it will be easier to follow the argument suggested in the previous hint.

Comment: Since |OX| and |OY| are fixed the minimum of |XY| is obtained when $∠XOY$ reaches its min value which is $135^∘$.
Is it clear that the min value of $∠XOY$ is $135^∘$?